# In Kubernetes Deployment, how not to start all the pods at once

Tags: kubernetes

I am using Kubernetes deployment. I wish to start the pods one by one. Not all at once. Is there any way. I do not want to use statefulSet.

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: my-container-image
        ports:
        - name: https
          containerPort: 8443
        volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /tmp
              name: app-vol
        restartPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      volumes:
        - name: app-vol
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: app-vol
```

Comment: Deployments do not guarantee ordered starts. 
StatefulSets are the way to achieve what you require. Could you explain why you are avoiding statefulsets?

Comment: This is an antipattern for deployments.

Comment: The requirements are very fuzzy here without more details. But maybe deployment strategy and lieveness/startuprobe is what they're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

> I wish to start the pods one by one. Not all at once. Is there any way. I do not want to use statefulSet.

Unfortunately you are trying to accomplish something with [`Deployment`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) that is achievable with [`Statefulset`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/). Is it possible to achieve the desired effect with deployment? A similar one can be obtained, but it will require [creating a custom script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66365892/limit-first-time-deployment-of-pods-in-kubernetes-using-kind-deployment/66641268#66641268) and it will be a non-standard solution.

However, this will not be a recommended solution. Statefulset works well for feed control during starts, and you shouldn't use anything else here.

To sum up: you should change the assumptions a bit and accept the statefulset, thanks to which you will achieve the result you want, or you should not control the order in which the pods are run.

As [rohatgisanat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4551228/rohatgisanat) mentioned in the comment:

> Deployments do not guarantee ordered starts. StatefulSets are the way to achieve what you require.